# Efficiently check if two large factorized multivariate polynomials are the same without expansion

Tags: polynomials

Given two large multivariate polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $m$ variables of degree $n$, which are factorized and have i.e. more than a 1000 terms, how can we check efficiently if they are the same?

To compare the coefficients, one would need to compute the coefficients, but I think expanding the polynomials can lead to too many terms to compute in reasonable time. Is there a smarter way? Or is this impossible because it is a necessity to check all coefficients?

Comment: Are the polynomials partially factorized or complete factorized ? If they are factorized into irreducible factors, the polynomials are equivalent if and only if they contain the same factors with the same multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That essentially means that you want to solve the notoriously hard problem of [polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) in a setting where the polynomials are given as algebraic circuits (consisting of "formulas" for the factors). Any progress there is warmly welcome, because a large community of world-class researchers hardly made any breakthroughs in the past dozen years or so, at least from a practical perspective. To the best of my knowledge, it's also one of the big, big open problems where we do not even have a good idea about its place in the computational complexity hierarchy except for highly restricted settings.

Peter's idea is that you should evaluate and compare both polynomials on an [unisolvent point set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisolvent_point_set) such as the [Padua points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padua_points). Unfortunately, determining a (small) such set is non-trivial in general, to say the least.

The practitioner's solution to that: rely on the [Schwartz-Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma) and plug in as many random points as necessary until the probability of a false positive is low enough. E.g., $10^{-10}$ times your estimate on the combined probability that there is a sudden earthquake destroying your machine, a bit flip due to radiation, a compiler bug that spoils some fancier algorithm, or (if all that's too small) the probability that you introduce a bug while you implement or design that algorithm...

Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Two UNIVARIATE polynomials of degree $n$ are identical, if they coincide at $n+1$ places, for example at the numbers $0,...,n$.

To formulate it more mathematically, if $f(n)=g(n)$ for $n=0,...,d\ $ and $deg(f)=deg(g)=d\ $, then we can conculde $f=g$.

This can be easily checked even for monster polynomials.

If we have two variables (lets say $x$ and $y$), we can fix $x$ and get a univariate polynomial. If the polynomial has degree $d$ with respect to $x$, I think we can also use the above idea, but I am not sure, whether it actually works.

If yes, we could use the method for arbitary polynomials.

In practice you could also do the following :

Evaluate the difference of the polynomials at some random points.

If the value is not $0$ at any point, the polynomials must be distinct.

If you get $0$ at all the points, you have a very good chance that the polynomials are equal.

Maybe, from a mathematical point of view, this method is debateable. But it should be sufficient for practical purpose.

Comment: But what about multivariate polynomials?

Comment: The idea behind this is, is that polynomials are linear in their coefficients, thus by evaluating them you get a constraint for a linear system of equations on the coefficients. One evaluation gives you one constraint, thus one would need a linear number of evaluations in the number of coefficients to fully "specify" the polynomials, I guess. But I'm still hoping for a better solution as the input size can be smaller than the number of coefficients.